# How to pull price at specific time

Tags: pine-script

I want to pull the price in pine at a specific time but could not find a solution in the manual or documentation. I want to compare the price at a specific time with the opening price of the day and additionally the opening price of the day with the closing price of the previous day.

I can pull the price for the current day and the previous day, but how can I pull the price at a specific time, e.g. 10 a.m. of the day to compare it with the opening price?

```
DayOpen = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open)
PrevDayClose = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close)[1]
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [timestamp](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_timestamp) & [Ternary conditional operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_%7Bquestion%7D%7Bcolon%7D).

Something like that:

```
i_period = input.time(timestamp('2022-01-31 10:00 GMT-3'), 'Start Time')
period = time >= i_period and time[1] < i_period
periodPrice = ta.valuewhen(period, close, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hour` and `minute` built-in variables to determine the time.

Here is an example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

var price10 = 0.0
price10 := (hour== 10 and minute == 0) ? close : price10
DayOpen = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open)

plot(price10)
```

[image]